# Several Listviews with same scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I have in Flutter more than one `Listview` but using same scroll for both?

My idea is having something like this:

```
ListTile
ListTile
ListTile
...

Some content

ListTile
ListTile
ListTile
...
```

I could move that content inside the `Listview` itself but it gets a bit messy and I'd prefer having different widgets

Comment: You can try SingleChildScrollView and add content of both the listview inside a Container instead of Listview if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options , one is with `SingleChildScrollView`, `Column` and removing the scroll of your Lists, or also you can do it with Slivers.

This is a sample using the first option:

```dart
Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text("Group 1 : Item $index"),
              ),
              itemCount: 9,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text("Some content"),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text("Group 2 : Item $index"),
              ),
              itemCount: 9,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

If you want to use Slivers, check this awesome post from Emily Fortuna;  https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f

Comment: I got it working with `Slivers` before but `SingleChildScrollView` sounds more like something I'd need to use here. Any particular difference between them?

Comment: You have more control using Slivers, and ListView use Sliver under the hood